# Python: any lazy method for reading .xls files?

Tags: python, excel

I know how to read `.xls` files with `pandas`. However, it returns all the data. I want to load data on demand, I mean, I want a generator that returns the next row each time is iterated. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python) for general files.

I know `openpyxl` can do this, following [this webpage](https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-ridiculously-large-excel-files-in-python-44ba0a7bea24). However, it doesn't support old `.xls` files. It recommends me to use `xlrd`, however, I don't know how to do what I want with that package.

[The documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/on_demand.html) tells how to do that sheet by sheet, but not row by row (my file has only one sheet).

Comment: A pandas DataFrame has a built-in generator called *iterrows()* which is probably what you need

Comment: I checked with my data, and the `xlrd.open_workbook` output occupies 48 bytes, while the `pandas.read_excel` output takes 5,361 bytes. The test excel file is 32,256 bytes. I'm still wondering if `xlrd` is already doing a "lazy reading" by the things I need to acces data. But I would use `xlrd` seeing the sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas doesn't support lazy loading, it reads the file and keeps everything in memory.

[Polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars) -- an alternative to pandas -- supports lazy loading.
Unfortunately this isn't yet implemented for xls files.

One solution is to convert the excel file to csv and use the [scan_csv](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html) function.

```py
import polars as pl
pl.scan_csv("sample.csv")
<polars.internals.lazyframe.frame.LazyFrame object at 0x7f0ae95d1c00>
```

Comment: That's a solution, although I don't know if it's worth it. I mean, I don't want to store the `.csv` file, so the algorithm would be like write-read-delete and the file would use some space in the disk. Although this isn't a problem for my data.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Dataframe to LazyFrame:

```
import polars as pl
df = dflazy.lazy()
dflazy
```